# React Context api - Consumer Does Not re-render after context changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-context

I searched for an answer but could not find any, so I am asking here,
I have a consumer that updates the context, 
and another consumer that should display the context.
I am using react with typescript(16.3)

The Context(AppContext.tsx):

```
export interface AppContext {
    jsonTransactions: WithdrawTransactionsElement | null;
    setJsonTran(jsonTransactions: WithdrawTransactionsElement | null): void;
}

export const appContextInitialState : AppContext = {
    jsonTransactions: null,
    setJsonTran : (data: WithdrawTransactionsElement) => {
        return appContextInitialState.jsonTransactions = data;
    }
};

export const AppContext = React.createContext(appContextInitialState);
```

The Producer(App.tsx):

```
interface Props {}

class App extends React.Component<Props, AppContext> {

  state: AppContext = appContextInitialState;

  constructor(props : Props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <AppContext.Provider value={this.state}>
          <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
              <SubmitTransactionFile/>
              <WithdrawTransactionsTable />
            </header>
          </div>
        </AppContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The updating context consumer(SubmitTransactionFile.tsx)

```
class SubmitTransactionFile extends React.Component {

    private fileLoadedEvent(file: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, context: AppContext): void{
        let files = file.target.files;
        let reader = new FileReader();
        if (files && files[0]) {
            reader.readAsText(files[0]);
            reader.onload = (json) =>  {
                if (json && json.target) {
                    // @ts-ignore -> this is because result field is not recognized by typescript compiler
                    context.setJsonTran(JSON.parse(json.target.result))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <AppContext.Consumer>
                { context  =>
                    <div className="SubmitTransactionFile">
                        <label>Select Transaction File</label><br />
                        <input type="file" id="file" onChange={(file) =>
                            this.fileLoadedEvent(file, context)} />
                        <p>{context.jsonTransactions}</p>
                    </div>
                }
            </AppContext.Consumer>
        )
    }
}


export default SubmitTransactionFile;
```

and finaly the display consumer(WithdrawTransactionsTable.tsx):

```
class WithdrawTransactionsTable extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <AppContext.Consumer>
                { context  =>
                    <div>
                        <label>{context.jsonTransactions}</label>
                    </div>
                }
            </AppContext.Consumer>
        )
    }
}

export default WithdrawTransactionsTable;
```

It is my understanding that after `fileLoadedEvent` function  is called the `context.setJsonTran` should re-render the other consumers and `WithdrawTransactionsTable` component should be re-rendered , but it does not.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: This probably was not OP's cause, but I had a very similar issue. In my case I had accidentally included another AppContext.Provider in one of my nested components. This was distorting behaviour, because any deeper children were not speaking to the Provider that I was expecting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you update the state, you aren't triggering a re-render of the Provider and hence the consumer data doesn't change. You should update the state using setState and assign context value to provider like

```
class App extends React.Component<Props, AppContext> {
  constructor(props : Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
         jsonTransactions: null,
         setJsonTran: this.setJsonTran
    };
  }

  setJsonTran : (data: WithdrawTransactionsElement) => {
        this.setState({
             jsonTransactions: data
        });
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <AppContext.Provider value={this.state}>
          <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
              <SubmitTransactionFile/>
              <WithdrawTransactionsTable />
            </header>
          </div>
        </AppContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `setJsonTran` just mutates the default value of the context which will not cause the `value` given to the `Provider` to change.

You could instead keep the `jsonTransactions` in the topmost state and pass down a function that will change this state and in turn update the `value`.

**Example**

```
const AppContext = React.createContext();

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    jsonTransactions: null
  };

  setJsonTran = data => {
    this.setState({ jsonTransactions: data });
  };

  render() {
    const context = this.state;
    context.setJsonTran = this.setJsonTran;

    return (
      <AppContext.Provider value={context}>
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <SubmitTransactionFile />
            <WithdrawTransactionsTable />
          </header>
        </div>
      </AppContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

```js
const AppContext = React.createContext();

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    jsonTransactions: null
  };

  setJsonTran = data => {
    this.setState({ jsonTransactions: data });
  };

  render() {
    const context = this.state;
    context.setJsonTran = this.setJsonTran;

    return (
      <AppContext.Provider value={context}>
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <SubmitTransactionFile />
            <WithdrawTransactionsTable />
          </header>
        </div>
      </AppContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

class SubmitTransactionFile extends React.Component {
  fileLoadedEvent(file, context) {
    let files = file.target.files;
    let reader = new FileReader();
    if (files && files[0]) {
      reader.readAsText(files[0]);
      reader.onload = json => {
        if (json && json.target) {
          // slice just to not output too much in this example
          context.setJsonTran(json.target.result.slice(0, 10));
        }
      };
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AppContext.Consumer>
        {context => (
          <div className="SubmitTransactionFile">
            <label>Select Transaction File</label>
            <br />
            <input
              type="file"
              id="file"
              onChange={file => this.fileLoadedEvent(file, context)}
            />
            <p>{context.jsonTransactions}</p>
          </div>
        )}
      </AppContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}

class WithdrawTransactionsTable extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <AppContext.Consumer>
        {context => (
          <div>
            <label>{context.jsonTransactions}</label>
          </div>
        )}
      </AppContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This helped clue me in on my issue.  In my case, I was using my context to represent an array.  When I attempted to push or splice the array and return this in my reducer, React would not see that as an update.  I solved mine by nesting the array as a property within the context state, like { myArray: [] }.  It was your use of the word "mutates" that clued me in to what I was overlooking... Thanks!