# How to change context in Consumer instead of Provider?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I found this question which answers to this problem with adding all context change functions to the topmost parent. [React Context api - Consumer Does Not re-render after context changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54831399/react-context-api-consumer-does-not-re-render-after-context-changed)

But this is awkward, I want the functions that change the context in the components that change it. Let's say I have a button that changes something in the content, I want to have the handleChange() in that component instead of clogging my parent with functions and states that don't belong there.

Is this possible to outsource context logic to components?

Comment: Please, try to include some relevant code to better represent your problem.

Comment: I have no code for this

Comment: Make sue to add the javascript tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`context` is a just a fancy technique of passing `props` without worring about hierarchy.

Decoupling the data flow is the only differential when comparing with normal `props`. So changing the value of a `context` comes with the some caveats.

When you need to change a shared state between parent and child you need to **lift your state up** and pass down a way of changing it. With `context` is no different

---

Assume the following provider which pass down a `theme` and a way of chage it

```
export const context = createContext()
const { Provider } = context

export const ThemeProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState({ color: 'foo' })
    const value = { theme, setTheme }
    return (
        <Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </Provider>
    )
}
```

You still need to pass down a handler to change the state. To change `theme` from inside a `Component` (which is descendent of `ThemeProvider`) you can do like this

```
import { useContext } from 'react'
import {context} from './ThemeProvider'

const Component = () =>{
    const {theme, setTheme} = useContext(context)

    const handleChange = () => setTheme({color:'blue'})

    return <button onClick={handleChange}>Change</button>
}
```

---

Usually (not necessarily) `Providers` are declared in the top-level component `App.js`

```
//App.js
import { ThemeProvider } from './ThemeProvider'

const App = () =>{
    <ThemeProvider>
         <RestOffYourApp />
    </ThemeProvider>
}
```

Comment: And would I add ThemeProvider to App.js?

Comment: It's just an example of how to modify your context

Comment: Yes, I understood the example but take I'd want to use it in this way, how would I add this to App.js

Comment: Updating the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the parent to have state and state-altering functions, just **don't use context** - it sounds like local [component state](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html) is all you are looking for.

Comment: No, the components are supposed to be siblings. So a button should change a prop in the context and another sibling on the same level should update on that change.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need use useReducer. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

You create a single `reducer` with the help of `useReducer` and pass it into `Context`. After that, you can use `state` and the `dispatch` from any component that is connected to the context.

**Links:**

- https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer
- https://medium.com/octopus-labs-london/replacing-redux-with-react-hooks-and-context-part-1-11b72ffdb533
- [When to use native React.useReducer Hook and how it differentiate from Redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54576865/when-to-use-native-react-usereducer-hook-and-how-it-differentiate-from-redux)
- https://www.simplethread.com/cant-replace-redux-with-hooks/

Comment: Or you can use multiple `useState` in the parent component and pass from through `Context`. But it seems to me that this is not the best solution.

Comment: Is this possible in a class-based App?

Comment: Hooks are used only in functional components